# what is the benefit to use form builder?

Tags: php, laravel, laravelcollective

Consider that i have a contact form in my contact page,

So why should i use something like [laravel collective](https://laravelcollective.com) that is a form builder.

I can simply write down my html codes in contact view like this:

```
<input class="form-control" name="company" type="text">
```

instead of this :

```
{{ Form::text('company', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

**What is the benefit?**

Comment: I'll refer you here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969746/laravel-form-methods-vs-traditional-coding

Answer (score 0):

- Cleaner syntax. Compare for example a traditional HTML select vs using [`Form::select('name', $array)`](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists).
- Integrated [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) protection.
- Integrated URLs to named routes, actions and RESTful controllers of your application. If use routes in your form URL and you cange a route URL all your models will still work.
- [Form Model Binding](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#form-model-binding) to populate form with data from your models.
- Automatic form fields population with flash (old) input.

You can also refer to the laravel Documentation
[Laravel Doc for form Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html)