# What is the advantage of using laravelcollective/html component over using the regular simple HTML tags to build view elements?

Tags: php, html, laravel-5, laravelcollective

Do we really need extra component to build HTML elements when we can do it with simple html tags?

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'Controller@method']) !!}
...
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

is equivalent with

```
<form action="{{url('Controller@method')}}">
...
</form>

Form::label('email', 'E-Mail Address', ['class' => 'awesome']);
```

is equivalent with

```
<label class='awesome' name='email'> E-Mail Address</label>
```

etc...

Are there things we can not achieve using the regular html tags? And if so, Is it ok to use mixed? (html tags and laravelcollective elemnts)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't see a benefit for yourself then you probably don't need it.

I found myself using it less and less and then eventually just stopped pulling it in altogether.

I think [Taylor](https://g.co/kgs/szK6G3) himself must have come to the same conclusion as otherwise, it would still be in Laravel core rather than a separate package.

Without a doubt, Laravel is one of the top names on the market and blade templating is indeed a good template engine.

Here are some of the reasons why you should use Laravel Collective

- When you open a form you can give a route to it.
- The method and the action are defined by blade based on the given
  route.
- With blade you can create macro's and view composers.
- Blade is not realy slow because laravel cache the compiled views.
- With blade you can extend and include views which is more DRY(Don't
  Repeat Yourself) Blade can automatically escape you're data with
  {{{$var}}}.
- If you've to write a multi-language application blade and laravel
  comes with easy methods to do achieve this.

Reference from comments in the question:

[Laravel Form methods VS traditional coding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25970197/8685260)

Comment: I strongly agree with : "I laravelcollective must have come to the same conclusion as otherwise, it would still be in Laravel core rather than a separate package."